# Spring Security Authenticate multiple apps with an external one

Tags: security, spring, cas

I'm trying to make a central point of authentication.

The goal is to have **N** spring security apps that use the same external application to login/logout.
Now I managed to do that, using [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas). However, I'm not automatically logged in through all the applications.

Use case:
1. access first app
2. redirected to CAS, login
3. redirected to first app logged in.
4. access second app
5. redirect to CAS login, again, WHY ?

I managed to resolve it, added the property sendRenew to false:

```
<bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
    <property name="service" value="https://****/j_spring_cas_security_check"/>
    <property name="sendRenew" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: sort of, I'm still having trouble finding a 'guidline' of some sort..